Terraform cloudbuild trigger: Error 400: Repository mapping does not exist
I am trying to provision a cloudbuild v1 trigger within my GCP project, however I run into the following issue:
Error: Error creating Trigger: googleapi: Error 400: Repository mapping does not exist. Please visit https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers;region=europe-west4/connect?project=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX to connect a repository to your project

Terraform code:
resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "test_cloudbuild_trigger" {
  project  = "<project_id>"
  name     = "test-build"
  filename = "cloudbuild.yaml"
  location = "europe-west4" # I tried lots of different locations / global

  source_to_build {
    uri       = "https://github.com/<org>/<repo>"
    repo_type = "GITHUB"
    ref       = "refs/heads/main"
  }

  github {
    push {
      tag = ".*"
    }
  }
}

I am 100% certain that the repository mapping does exist for that zone, I also tried different zones and setting the mapping on global level. When I try to create the trigger via the console I don't run into any issues.


In case someone else runs into a similar issue, this might help. It turns out that when I change the configuration slightly, it seems to work fine:
resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "test_cloudbuild_trigger" {
  project  = "<project_id>"
  name     = "test-build"
  filename = "cloudbuild.yaml"
  location = "europe-west4"

  github {
    owner = "<org>"
    name = "<repo>"
    push {
      tag = ".*"
    }
  }
}


Thanks, this doc shows the config: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudbuild_trigger#nested_source_to_build
